# How to Make a button in Google Sites with the help of gscript so that it can can fetch user Mail ID and then store it in googlesheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As I used Gscript for development I created a .gs file and then .html file which have required code according to problem, but I am not able to get output.

The following lines contain my .gs file code:-

```
function doGet(){
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('hunny');
}
```

The following lines contain my HTML file code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   
    <button onclick="getEmailone()">Click me</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
        function getEmailone(){
          const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
          const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-p6f7JbrGWFS6oCpZDy0Yfdk--z1YbSuGxtJ--SUfZE/edit#gid=0");
          const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
          const userMail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

          if (userMail == null){
            targetSheet.appendRow(ui.prompt("Enter email").getResponseText());
          } else {
            targetSheet.appendRow([userMail]);
          }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
<script>
function getEmailone(){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();//this is serverside code
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-p6f7JbrGWFS6oCpZDy0Yfdk--z1YbSuGxtJ--SUfZE/edit#gid=0");//server side code
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//server side code
  const userMail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();server side code

  if (userMail == null){
    targetSheet.appendRow(ui.prompt("Enter email").getResponseText());//server side code
  } else {
    targetSheet.appendRow([userMail]);//server side code
  }
}
</script>
```

You will need to do something like this:

```
<script>
function getEmailone(){
  //get params if any
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(robj){
    //do something with robj
  })
  .someServerSideFunction(params);
}
</script>
```

GS:

```
function someServerSideFunction() {
  //do whatever you want here and 
  //return back to html
}
```

Comment: Then what to do. THANKS in advance.

Comment: Can you please more elaborate this. I would be highly thankful to you.

Comment: Well I don't know much about Google sites.  In a website you might be able identify a visitor by an ip address or even their server address but as far as getting their email address that's out of the question unless the website has a relationship with Google like an advertising relationship and they're willing to share your visitors email with you for a fee.  So I don't  really know how you plan to get the user information I just know that the structure of your methodology is incorrect as for the details to acquire what you want I can't provide that.  You'll have to determine that on your own.